# UIPageControl of a UIPageViewController sometimes does not get updated when it is scrolled to next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have created a subclass of `UIPageViewController` with `transitionStyle` = `.scroll` and have implemented the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` methods that are responsible for showing the `UIPageControl` as follows-

```
func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

The page view controller has `modalPresentationStyle` of `.custom` such that when the view controller is presented it does not occupy fullscreen.

I have observed sometimes when I scroll the page view controller to show the next child view controller, the page indicator is not updated. The following GIF shows the problem

[image]

Can anyone point out how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below method for the page change acknowledgement.

```
  func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, 
 didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: 
 [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

    pageControl.currentPage = arrViewController.index(of: pageContentViewController) ?? 0

}
```